# TSQL datetime size

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, time

I was browsing msdn in regards to data type sizes in T-SQL and noticed something I'm a bit confused on.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx, datetime uses 8 bytes and stores a date from years 1753-9999 with a time precision of hh:mm:ss[.nnn]. Now if you look at date and time separately, time uses 3-5 bytes to store hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] and date uses 3 bytes to store from years 0 - 9999.

What confuses me is that using date and time separately gives you a wider range of years and time with four more digits of precision than datetime, yet they both use 8 bytes? Why does datetime have a smaller range and less precision yet uses the same size to store itself?

Comment: `DATETIME` has been around since way back when - it's probably not as optimized as the newer `DATE` and `TIME` (and `DATETIME2`) datatypes.

Comment: Agreed with marc_s - if you want (more) efficient, use `datetime2`. `datetime` has existed for decades now, and is not necessarily the best way to go.

Comment: Even storing DATE years 0-9,999 as 3 bytes seems completely arbitrary.  3 bytes can contain 2^24 values (almost 17 million).  But 10,000 years only contains 3.6 million distinct dates.  So they actually *could* have stored years from -20,000 (20,000 BCE) through 20,000.  Anyone have any idea why they would not try to use the full set of available values?  I presume something about the internal storage structure makes it more efficient (processing-wise) to store fewer values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Datetime data type precedes the separate date and time data types. The Datetime data type uses 8 bytes, as two integers. The first integer stores 01/01/1900 as 0 any days before 1900 are stored as a negative number of days before and any date after is stored as a positive integer denoting the number of days after 01/01/1900.

The reason the date only starts at 1753 is that this is the start of the Gregorian calendar and any days before this you need to know the country to determine the date. This was the decision made by the original Sybase developers, from which Sql Server is descended.

The time integer portion stores the number of ticks since midnight. A tick is 1/300 second.

Good examples and info can be found here;
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server
and http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes